# why singleton class when i can create a normal class to have only one instance

Tags: .net, vb.net, singleton

I am trying to understand Singleton Pattern in detail.

I have come across the following example online which works fine and it prevents creating more than one instance of a class;

```
Public Class Singleton

Private Shared SP As Singleton
Private InnerList As New Collections.ArrayList()

Private Sub New()
End Sub

Public Shared Function Create() As Singleton
    If SP Is Nothing Then SP = New Singleton()
    Return SP
End Function

Public ReadOnly Property List As Collections.ArrayList
    Get
        Return InnerList
    End Get
End Property
End Class
```

I have created another test class which can also prevent creating more than one instance of a class;

```
Public Class test

Private Shared SP As test
Private InnerList As New Collections.ArrayList()

Private Sub New()
End Sub

Public Shared Function Create() As test
    If SP Is Nothing Then SP = New test
    Return SP
End Function

Public ReadOnly Property List As Collections.ArrayList
    Get
        Return InnerList
    End Get
End Property
End Class
```

So what is the main differene in above two classes?

```
    Dim o As test = test.Create
    Dim o2 As test = test.Create

    o.List.Add("First")
    o.List.Add("Second")
    o.List.Add("Third")

    MsgBox(o2.List.Item(1).ToString()) --result 'second'
```

Comment: The main advantage of a singleton is that some guys wrote a book 20 years ago saying it was a design pattern. In practice, [it is a horrible idea](http://jalf.dk/singleton/), and you are right, you should instead just create a class and instantiate it once.

Comment: What you have implemented is a Singleton. What is the difference among the 2 codes other than the name of the class? (I am not expert in .net) About the usefulness of patterns, they help to solve problems that you find in your coding often without having to reinvent the wheel and having a reference that helps you to solve the issues related to implementation details in the solution.